# datetime objects in list

Tags: python, list, datetime

```
#3. add times as field
self.scheduled_transmitions = self.scheduled_transmitions_copy[:]
self.scheduled_transmitions_copy = []
self.datetime_clock = start_datetime
counter = 0
for scheduled_transmition in self.scheduled_transmitions:
    print(self.datetime_clock)
    self.scheduled_transmitions[counter]["datetime"] = self.datetime_clock
    self.datetime_clock = self.datetime_clock+datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(scheduled_transmition["duration_in_seconds"]))
        
    self.scheduled_transmitions_copy.append(self.scheduled_transmitions[counter])
    counter = counter + 1

print("------------")
self.scheduled_transmitions = self.scheduled_transmitions_copy[:]
self.scheduled_transmitions_copy = []

for scheduled_transmition in self.scheduled_transmitions:
    print(scheduled_transmition["datetime"])

    
return 1
```

The up code has wrong output.

```
#3. add times as field
self.scheduled_transmitions = self.scheduled_transmitions_copy[:]
self.scheduled_transmitions_copy = []
self.datetime_clock = start_datetime
for scheduled_transmition in self.scheduled_transmitions:
    print(self.datetime_clock)
    entry = {"datetime":self.datetime_clock}
    self.datetime_clock = self.datetime_clock+datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(scheduled_transmition["duration_in_seconds"]))
        
    self.scheduled_transmitions_copy.append(entry)

print("------------")
self.scheduled_transmitions = self.scheduled_transmitions_copy[:]
self.scheduled_transmitions_copy = []

for scheduled_transmition in self.scheduled_transmitions:
    print(scheduled_transmition["datetime"])

    
return 1
```

But the last one does not.

Why?

Output of first code (wrong):

```
2020-11-08 18:05:20.054000
2020-11-08 18:06:48.054000
2020-11-08 18:08:16.054000
2020-11-08 18:09:44.054000
2020-11-08 18:11:12.054000
2020-11-08 18:12:40.054000
2020-11-08 18:14:08.054000
2020-11-08 18:15:36.054000
2020-11-08 18:17:04.054000
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
------------
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
2020-11-08 18:18:32.054000
```

Output of seconds code.

```
2020-11-08 18:03:13.265000
2020-11-08 18:04:41.265000
2020-11-08 18:06:09.265000
2020-11-08 18:07:37.265000
2020-11-08 18:09:05.265000
2020-11-08 18:10:33.265000
2020-11-08 18:12:01.265000
2020-11-08 18:13:29.265000
2020-11-08 18:14:57.265000
2020-11-08 18:16:25.265000
------------
2020-11-08 18:03:13.265000
2020-11-08 18:04:41.265000
2020-11-08 18:06:09.265000
2020-11-08 18:07:37.265000
2020-11-08 18:09:05.265000
2020-11-08 18:10:33.265000
2020-11-08 18:12:01.265000
2020-11-08 18:13:29.265000
2020-11-08 18:14:57.265000
2020-11-08 18:16:25.265000
```

Comment: What output are you expecting for the second part? This looks like there's a section of code missing, possibly something along the lines of `start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()` that could account for the timestamps in the second output.

Comment: @MostlyHarmless if you see the last list output, there all the datetimes are the same.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: @martineau i try it. But with runnable example there is no error.

Comment: @martineau the schedule_transmitions list aren't changed by a thread or somewhere.

Comment: Question eddited.

Comment: The [mre] should be something others can run (and maybe fix). The code in your question is just an incomplete part of class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that happens but the following code works:

```
    #3. add times as field
    self.scheduled_transmitions = self.scheduled_transmitions_copy[:]
    self.scheduled_transmitions_copy = []
    self.datetime_clock = start_datetime
    for scheduled_transmition in self.scheduled_transmitions:
        print(self.datetime_clock)
        entry = scheduled_transmition.copy()
        entry["datetime"]=self.datetime_clock
        self.datetime_clock = self.datetime_clock+datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(scheduled_transmition["duration_in_seconds"]))
        
        
        self.scheduled_transmitions_copy.append(entry)
    
    print("------------")
    self.scheduled_transmitions = self.scheduled_transmitions_copy[:]
    self.scheduled_transmitions_copy = []
    
    for scheduled_transmition in self.scheduled_transmitions:
        print(scheduled_transmition["datetime"])
    
        
    return 1
```

I copy the list element (dictionary) using `dictionary.copy()` method.